# Comparing String against JSON.getString

Tags: java, android, json, compare

I'm a little bit stuck on this one. I'm trying to compare a String against a jsonobject.getString and it seems whatever I do they do not match:

```
String date = scoreJson.getString("Date");
if (dateString.equals(date))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

The value of dateString is assigned here:

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = calendar.get(calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), month = calendar.get(calendar.MONTH), year = calendar.get(calendar.YEAR);

//months start at 0 in calendar
month += 1;

//use builder to create the dateString
builder.append(year).append("-").append(month).append("-").append(day);
dateString = builder.toString();
```

When I view both Strings in debug they show "2015-05-18", however they will not match in a conditional statement. Does anyone have any idea why, and how I could compare them?

Thanks.

Edit: The JSON object will come back in this format:

```
{"ScoreData":{"Username":"testUser","Id":"8fb25209-863a-410b-a440-
b5b57a903ee1","Date":"2015-02-25","Score":"25.3"}}
```

I am retrieving the values from it here and saving to sharedprefs:

```
//response comes back as two JSONObjects, this makes the inner object into a new JSON
JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(response);

JSONObject scoreJson = new JSONObject(responseJson.getString("ScoreData"));

String date = scoreJson.getString("Date");
puzzleScore = scoreJson.getString("Score");

SharedPreferencesWrapper.saveToPrefs(c, "score-" + date, puzzleScore);
```

I am then checking for the key here:

```
puzzleScore = SharedPreferencesWrapper.getFromPrefs(c, "score-" + dateString, "NotFound");

if (!puzzleScore.contains("NotFound"))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have non-printable characters in the string. Also why not compare Date instances instead?

Comment: Json strings include " so try replaceAll("\"", "") before comparing.

Comment: @AlexisC. Hmm it's possible, I'm using String compares because the place in my code where I need to compare them is to retrieve an item from sharedpreferences, for example:

`code 
SharedPreferencesWrapper.saveToPrefs(c, "score-" + date, puzzleScore);`

`code 
puzzleScore = SharedPreferencesWrapper.getFromPrefs(c, "score-" + dateString, "NotFound");`

Comment: Comparing equality by toString() representation is ugly. toString() is usually used for representation, not comaprison. Better idea is to parse date obtained from JSON to Calendar and compare Calendar objects.

Comment: @FilipMalczak. Unfortunately I can't parse to a date as I need the two Strings to match to pull the key from sharedpreferences.

Comment: You can keep both parsed and unparsed versions and compare parsed ones, but use unparsed as keys.

Comment: can you provide a complete example, including a sample of the JSON?

Comment: @FilipMalczak. I'm saving multiple keys to the same date so unfortunately I can't just use the date as the key otherwise that'd probably be a good solution.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek. Ok I will update the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding `toString()` after this `scoreJson.getString("Date")`, so the code would be like `scoreJson.getString("Date").toString()`.

I think it is a problem with encoding. If that doesn't work, check for whitespaces around the string. You can remove starting & trailing whitespaces with `trim()`.

Hope this helps, good luck~